# Why is the admission review triggered twice when injecting another container into the pod?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have this `MutatingWebhookConfiguration` and a service that injects a sidecar.

```yaml
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: example-sidecar-injector
webhooks:
  - name: sidecar-injector.rainbowstack.dev
    clientConfig:
      caBundle: ...
      service:
        namespace: example
        name: admission-webhooks
        path: /inject-sidecar

    admissionReviewVersions: ["v1"]
    sideEffects: None
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    reinvocationPolicy: IfNeeded
    failurePolicy: Fail

    matchPolicy: Equivalent

    rules:
      - apiGroups: [""]
        apiVersions: [v1]
        operations: [CREATE, UPDATE]
        resources: [pods]
        scope: Namespaced

    objectSelector:
      matchExpressions:
        - key: inject-sidecar-example
          operator: In
          values:
            - enabled
```

When I create a pod, the webhook service is getting 2 admission reviews posted.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busyboxs
  namespace: example
  labels:
    name: busybox
    inject-sidecar-example: enabled
spec:
  containers:
    - name: busybox
      image: busybox
      command:
        - sleep
        - infinity
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "8Mi"
          cpu: "1m"
        limits:
          memory: "64Mi"
          cpu: "10m"
```

I am not sure what is the cause for this. Is it because the mutating webhook adds another container to the pod?

After the patch, the container list is like the below (truncated for brevity).

```yaml
containers:
  - name: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - infinity
    image: busybox
  - name: sidecar
    command:
      - sleep
      - infinity
    image: busybox
```

AFAIK, the webhook server does its mutation even before the pod is created. That's why I think it can't be because the additional container forces a recreation of the pod. Both review requests are also for the CREATE operation.

Why is Kubernetes sending the request twice, the second time with the sidecar already in the spec?

The webhook code is the below.

```golang
func myhook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    review := &adm.AdmissionReview{}
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(review)

    // checks omited for brevity

    patchType := adm.PatchTypeJSONPatch
    patch, _ := json.Marshal(jsonpatch.New().
        Add("/spec/containers/1", core.Container{
            Name:    "sidecar",
            Image:   "busybox",
            Command: []string{"sleep", "infinity"},
        }),
    )

    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&adm.AdmissionReview{
        TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
            APIVersion: "admission.k8s.io/v1",
            Kind:       "AdmissionReview",
        },
        Response: &adm.AdmissionResponse{
            UID:       review.Request.UID,
            Patch:     patch,
            PatchType: &patchType,
            Allowed:   true,
        },
    })
}
```

Kubernetes version is `1.21.2` and this is an AKS cluster.

You can see in the logs that 2 separate admission reviews are sent at the same time.

```
2022/03/06 18:00:24 Admission review received, request id:: e8d16750-eb0c-43eb-876c-85951271778d
2022/03/06 18:00:24 Admission review received, request id:: a0f56647-a94f-48e4-aa32-1e47740b6444
```

In the event logs, I don't actually see this, but the pod that are created.

```
example     0s          Normal    Pulled              pod/busybox                               Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 973.41353ms
example     0s          Normal    Created             pod/busybox                               Created container busybox
example     0s          Normal    Started             pod/busybox                               Started container busybox
example     0s          Normal    Pulling             pod/busybox                               Pulling image "busybox"
example     0s          Normal    Pulled              pod/busybox                               Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 964.829463ms
example     0s          Normal    Created             pod/busybox                               Created container sidecar
example     0s          Normal    Started             pod/busybox                               Started container sidecar
```

Comment: How do you figure out that the request is Sent twice?

Comment: @p.... By logging the requests. It also failed at first because it tried to inject a container with duplicate name the second time around.  I have now a check in the webhook to see if the sidecar is already in the spec and skip patching it again if so. That is probably a good idea anwayway since the hook also triggers on update. It still left me wondering why this is happening.

Comment: Can't really say for sure without looking into your webhook code.

Comment: @P.... I have added the code. it just adds a patch to add the sidecars to the container list.

Comment: Please also give more details on your Kubernetes environment - version, bare-metal installation or cloud provider.

Comment: @anarxz, I have added the info: Kubernetes version is `1.21.2` and this is an AKS cluster.

Comment: Could you please also share your logs on the requests to have a look?

Comment: @anarxz, I have added the logs. If you want to include some specific info in the logs, let me know. I have currently only the request ID for brevity, but I did also log the full review object at some point where I could see that on the second request the sidecar is already in the spec.